# Javascript - textarea

Tags: javascript

i have really a problem and do a research but cannot reach anything.

i have an admin panel and there is a textarea. Textarea consist of a javascript html panel.
[image]

but when i entered words, scrool bar does not occur , and the textarea reach its borders 
[image]

i really confused what will i do ? where is the scroll bar?

and you can download my js here

http://www.roosle.com/KQ5SJCD0CKRU/nicEdit.js.html

Comment: Would you please post the HTML code? I suspect that you simply need to add a `rows` attribute to the textarea, as in `<textarea rows="15"></textarea>`.

Comment: Maybe adding `overflow: scroll` would do the trick?

Comment: <div class="InputConteynerBigImage">
                          <textarea rows="0" cols="0" name="message" id="area1"></textarea>
                    </div> This is my textarea

Comment: <div class="InputConteynerBigImage">
                          <textarea rows="15" cols="0" name="message" id="area1"></textarea>
                    </div> i did it like that but nothing changed :(

Comment: borderTop:0,overflowY:"scroll",overflowX:"scroll" i made them both scroll, scrolls appear but still going down :S

Comment: i think it is because of my html but i didnt reach any solution <div class="InputConteynerBig">
                    <div class="InputConteynerText ITCAvantGardeStdMd">
                        İçerik
                    </div>
                         <div class="InputConteynerBigImage">
                          <textarea rows="" cols="" name="message" id="area1"></textarea>
                    </div>
       
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

try putting value in rows and cols like

```
<div class="InputConteynerBigImage"> <textarea rows="15" cols="30" name="message" id="area1"></textarea> </div>
```

and adjust them as needed.